# Is it possible to get the length of a chunked encoded file using a HEAD Request?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I have a feeling the answer to this will be no but multiple people tell me that a HEAD request can bypass the chunked encoding and come back with a content-length. I've looked around online and it seems to be mixed results, and if someone says that you can I can never find a code segment to get the length. I currently have a small example to try to get me something but it returns -1.

Code Segment:

```
    try {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        con.getInputStream();



        Log.i("OSMDB", "HEAD Request: " + con.getContentLength() );

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I found this code when I looked around and since it returns a -1 that means that the content-length is unknown which makes sense because the file is chunked encoded. And yet people still tell me that there is a way. So is there a way to get the length of a chunked encoded file without downloading it by using a HEAD Request? Or am I out of options because I received the negative value?

Answer (score 0):

As a client, there is no way for you to 'force' an HTTP server to respond with a Content-Length header. It is also not possible for a server to implement the behaviour you want without violating a '*SHOULD*-requirement' in the HTTP specifiction, which mandates that:

- the response to a HEAD request *SHOULD* contain the same headers as the matching GET request
- a Content-Length header *MUST NOT* be sent in a message also containing a Transfer-Encoding header

(*SHOULD* and *MUST NOT* used as specified in [BCP-14](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp14))

This means that if the server intends to respond to a GET request with chunked encoding, it should also indicate so in the response to a HEAD request for the same resource and if it does so, it is not allowed to include a Content-Length header in the response.

This makes sense if you consider that chunked encoding was intended e.g. for dynamically generated responses, where the server does not know the length of the data before starting transmission.

Comment: I figured as much. It does work if you have a content-length which is nice. I only have the chunked encoding problem for large text files which I can get around by changing the extension to .bin.